# MS Edge is not using system default printer

Tags: windows, browser, printing, settings, microsoft-edge

I am changing system default printer programmatically via python method.

```
import win32print

printer1 = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(printer1)
```

Setting default system printer works well.

My issue is that MS Edge browser is not reflecting system default, but it's using latest used one. For all other documents system default is used.
It almost seems like an Edge bug. Can anyone fix this strange browser behavior and make it to use system default printer reliably?

```
import win32print

printer1 = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(printer1)
```

Works well as expected and set Windows 10 system default printer to printer1 that is in this case Microsoft Print to PDF.

But I was expecting also MS Edge will reflect system default printer, but it is using latest used one instead- see in picture when I use Ctrl+P.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVR96.png)

To verify what is really system default printer Ctrl+Shift+P
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB1qc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Windows "Feature" you need to ask your users to uncheck the box.

However when altering, any USER setting your code should

- STORE Current state
- Apply a TEMPORARY change
- RESTORE User settings

All possible using PrintUI.exe and the supplied Printing VBS code

Mine are in several places !! but primarily

file:///C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US

[image]

NOTE the comment below from @oorii, that there is a secondary way to set Edge default behaviour in combination with the above.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge (Edge Key(Folder) need to be created) then there is needed to create DWORD 32-bit Value: "PrintPreviewUseSystemDefaultPrinter", Value data: must be set to "1". After Browser restart this finally works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I didn't mention that, but yes it is behaving that way even with unchecked/checked _Let Windows manage my default printer_ feature. In fact Edge is not reflecting system default printer in any way. I will try to play with VBS code a bit. Thanks.

Comment: In fact printer is working well and if any local document is printed the dialog is reflecting correct printer (system default one). Only browser is using different one (latest used instead).

Comment: Finally I got that. Yes solution is in Windows registry.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge (Edge Key(Folder) need to be created) then there is needed to create DWORD 32-bit Value: "PrintPreviewUseSystemDefaultPrinter", Value data: must be set to "1". After Browser restart this finally works.

Comment: I see but this is ok in this case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes I see - in this case it will be small group of 4 users - Medicals. But anyway I'll need to test it in their environment and make sure it makes no troubles.